# Angular TypeScript, expecting string but get '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is part of a class:

```
export class Token {
    constructor(
        private type: string,
        private encoded: string) {
        ... ...
    }
    ... ...

    toString(): string {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

Call like this:

```
... ...    
let str: string = token.toString();
```

check the value it's

```
[object Object]
```

Expecting the string that was passed to the constructor.

Comment: How are you instantiating Token?

Comment: please provide plunker or jsfiddle of this application

Comment: console.log(%O, token.toString())

Comment: an object converted to a string equals [object Object], so your token value must be an object instead of what you are expecting (string). So ultimately you must be passing an object to the type parameter in your constructor

Comment: Thanks to everyone. The token object is generated from a JSON saved in localStorage. setToken(token: Token) {
 localStorage.setItem(this.KEY_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(token));
}

getToken(): Token {
    let token: Token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.KEY_TOKEN));
    return token;
  }

Comment: if the token object is saved in a variable instead of retrieved from localStorage then token.toString() returns a string that was set to the variable, which is as expected.

Comment: Did you solve this? was an error passing the object? Because i'm passing string and getting [object object]